# Are there any N1 rockets (the Soviet answer to the Saturn V) still in existence?

Tags: saturn-v, n-1

Knowing the work that went into the Saturn V, being able to see the size of it in person at the Kennedy Space Center was almost a religious experience. I would love to be able to see an N1. Are there any in existence?

I've read the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N1_(rocket)) and it seems like there aren't but I can't find much information.

Comment: Pretty sure Wikipedia is correct on this one.

Comment: Can you add a link to the specific Wikipedia page you are referencing back into your question? It's helpful because then readers can see what sources it cites for example an have some additional context. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No N1s remain intact as far as I know. Wikipedia is pretty clear about [the disposition of the individual N1s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N1_(rocket)#N1_vehicle_serial_numbers) constructed.

I found [a photo gallery](http://www.starbase1.co.uk/pages/N1-Galleries/Wreckage%20and%20Remains/index.html) showing various scraps and wreckage from the N1, including a garden shed made from a payload fairing, but the origins of the pictures is unclear. [Astronautix claims the "gazebos"](http://www.astronautix.com/n/n1.html) are at [Baikonur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baikonur_Cosmodrome), which seems plausible; that's probably where you'd go to get a look at actual N1 hardware, such as it is.

Comment: Thank you! It's a bummer there's not an intact one but seeing it Mad Max-y repurposed would be interesting on its own.